# (Java, mad-libs games) I'm getting two prompt input questions on one line when they should each have their own line

Tags: java

It's for a mad-libs game from a UW course. I'm not a student there but just following along.

The text file I'm getting information from looks like this:

```html
One of the most <adjective> characters in fiction is named
"Tarzan of the <plural-noun> ." Tarzan was raised by a/an
<noun> and lives in the <adjective> jungle in the
heart of darkest <place> . He spends most of his time
eating <plural-noun> and swinging from tree to <noun> .
Whenever he gets angry, he beats on his chest and says,
" <funny-noise> !" This is his war cry. Tarzan always dresses in
<adjective> shorts made from the skin of a/an <noun>
and his best friend is a/an <adjective> chimpanzee named
Cheetah. He is supposed to be able to speak to elephants and
<plural-noun> . In the movies, Tarzan is played by <person's-name> .
```

Here's the output of mine I'm having problems with:

> Please type a/an plural noun: Please type a/an noun:

I want these to be on their own separate lines (obviously). It only happens when two "< >" are on the same line.

Here's the part of the code I'm using:

```
Scanner search = new Scanner(file);

    while (search.hasNextLine()) {
        String prompt = search.next();

        if (prompt.startsWith("<") && prompt.endsWith(">")) {
            prompt = prompt.replace('<', ' ');
            prompt = prompt.replace('>', ':');
            prompt = prompt.replace('-', ' ');
            System.out.print("Please type a/an" + prompt + " ");
            String funnyText = console.next();
            output.print(funnyText + " ");
        } else {
            output.print(prompt + " ");
        }
    }
```

Hopefully one of you can figure this out and help me.

what I tried:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Homework {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Mad Libs.");
    System.out.println("I will ask you to provide various words");
    System.out.println("and phrases to fill in a story.");
    System.out.println("The result will be written to an output file.");
    System.out.println();

    Boolean menuLoop = false;

    while (menuLoop == false) {
        System.out.print("(C)reate mad-lib, (V)iew mad-lib, (Q)uit? ");
        String input = console.next();
        if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("c")) {
            create(console);
            menuLoop = true;
        } else if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("v")) {
            System.out.println("Game will play soon.");
            menuLoop = true;
        } else if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("q")) {
            System.out.println("Thanks for playing.");
            menuLoop = true;
        } else {
            menuLoop = false;
        }
    }
}

public static void create(Scanner console) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.print("Input file name: ");
    String inputFile = console.next();
    File file = new File(inputFile);

    while (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.print("File not found. Try again: ");
        inputFile = console.next();
        file = new File(inputFile);
    }
    System.out.print("Output file name: ");
    String outputFile = console.next();
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File(outputFile));
    System.out.println();

    Scanner search = new Scanner(file);

    while (search.hasNextLine()) {
        String prompt = search.next();

        if (prompt.startsWith("<") && prompt.endsWith(">")) {
            prompt = prompt.replace('<', ' ');
            prompt = prompt.replace('>', ':');
            prompt = prompt.replace('-', ' ');
            System.out.print("Please type a/an" + prompt + " ");
            String funnyText = console.next();
            output.print(funnyText + " ");
        } else {
            output.print(prompt + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Here's my output:

> Welcome to the game of Mad Libs.
>   I will ask you to provide various words
>   and phrases to fill in a story.
>   The result will be written to an output file.
>
> (C)reate mad-lib, (V)iew mad-lib, (Q)uit? c
>   Input file name: tarzan.txt
>   Output file name: output
>
> Please type a/an adjective: sadgs
>   Please type a/an plural noun: sagsd sdagsd
>   Please type a/an noun: Please type a/an adjective:

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.println` instead. That prints the output to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print does not output a newline at the end of the printed item(s). System.out.println will add a newline. So you can use System.out.println when you want the following output on a new line.

For example:

```
System.out.println("foo");
System.out.println("bar");
```

Gives

```
foo
bar
<blank line here>
```

While

```
System.out.print("foo");
System.out.print("bar");
```

Gives

```
foobar
```

You can create newlines anywhere you need them with

```
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: where do I put system.out.println because I've been trying that and it doesn't work

Comment: I think it happens because as it searches the line in the document or text file (hasNextLine) it comes up with two "<" and ">"

Comment: it happens when I type two words in the previous prompt

Comment: You can create newlines anywhere you need them with

System.out.println("")